# Opening files to read in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a cash machine simulation.
This is my code so far:

```
print ("Cash Machine\n")
input("Press Enter to begin...")
card_number = int(input("Enter your card number... "))


f = open((card_number + ".txt"),"r")
lines = f.readlines()

x = lines[1]
print(x)
```

Currently I have a text file called 123 in my folder. Inside the file is how much money the bank account 123 has, but I am having trouble trying to open the file.
Specifically with the line 6. I get an error saying 
"No such file or directory: 'card_number.txt'"
How can I make it work?
Thanks

Comment: use absolute paths instead of relative paths

Comment: try with: `f = open(card_number + ".txt","r")`

Answer (score 1):

You have to run this program in the same directory that contains the file or use the full path name. 
If running in the same directory, you can use the code you have. If not, you can tweak the code like this:

Edit: you are casting your input as an integer when it needs to be a string:

```
input("Press Enter to begin...")
card_number = input("Enter your card number... ")


f = open(card_number + ".txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()

x = lines[1]
print(x)
```

Comment: I am running the program in the same directory and I get this error-TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'